# Android Application tansfer result from main to second Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

In eclipse for Android Application, How do I transfer a number from display box to another Activity?

```
 Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
 calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
 {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
            EditText numberDos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numDos);
            TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

           double num = Double.parseDouble(number.getText().toString());
           double numDos = Double.parseDouble(numberDos.getText().toString());

           num = Double.parseDouble(batdroidCalc.multNum(num));

           num = num * numDos;

           display.setText(num + "");

        }
    });
```

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Use Intents to send data across

Comment: yes, just go through the "Building Your First App" from Android developers training guide, you need to use the "putExtra()" & "getExtra()"'s of the Intents. The above mentioned link will give you a nice introduction to Android as well. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In you button click add this:

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //your code
                        Intent i=new Intent(Yourpagename.this,Nextpage.class);
                        i.putExtra("value",display.getText().toString());
                         startActivity(i);   


                    }
                });
```

Then in the next page(Nextpage.class) you can get the value as:
Define a string like `String value` at your second page.

```
 value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
```

Dont forget to define your second activity in Android Manifest.xml.

Comment: public class Class2 extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_class2);
 
  String value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
  
   value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
     calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
     {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
                EditText numberDos = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numDos);
                TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

               double num = Double.parseDouble(number.getText().toString());
               double numDos = Double.parseDouble(numberDos.getText().toString());

               num = Double.parseDouble(batdroidCalc.multNum(num));

               num = num * numDos;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("num", numos);
                i.putExtra("numos", num);
                startActivity(i);



            }
        });
```

**NextActivity.class**

```
Intent iv= getIntent();
double val = iv.getExtras().getDouble("num");
double val1 = iv.getExtras().getDouble("numos");
```

Comment: the val and val1 are not being used,

Answer (score -1):

1.Intent with args
2.save the args in singleton object
3.boardcast
etc.